# Nagios plugin exist but not found - check_ping : No such file or directory

Tags: alma-linux

I run the following command ./check_ping (Nagios plugin) but it says the file or directory does not exist. However, the file does exist.

```
file check_ping
check_ping: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=78c644f711477d8987bc8e5b058bd10261a899a0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: Have you try to exec command with full path?

Comment: Missing libraries: glibc and libnsl.

Comment: Did you check if you have `libnsl`? what is the result of `ldd /path/to/check_ping`?

Comment: I've installed the missing libraries and it has fixed the issues.

Comment: Are you running on a 32bit platform? If not then why are you trying to run the 32bit version of `check_ping`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you are missing some library. You just need to install the library and the plugin should work fine.